# How to programatically type text anywhere using C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to be able to send text not in a console window but anywhere typing can be done such as code editor, input field, search bar etc.

I have the following code that involves the use of clipboard and sending keystrokes which works fine

```
// Create a generic keyboard event structure
INPUT ip;
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0;
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

const char* output = "Test";
const size_t len = strlen(output) + 1;
HGLOBAL hMem =  GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, len);
memcpy(GlobalLock(hMem), output, len);
GlobalUnlock(hMem);
OpenClipboard(0);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem);
CloseClipboard();

// Hold the "Ctrl" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;ip.ki.dwFlags = 0;SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(500);

// Press the "V" key
keybd_event('V', 0x1c, 0, 0);
Sleep(500);

// Release the "Ctrl" key
ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
Sleep(500);
```

The problem is that it removes any useful data that might already be present in the clipboard. It is too long and I feel there must be a simpler way to do this and I need to be able to use this code for unicode characters also. Another way might be to individually send keystrokes for different letter keys but that would be even longer and the problem of sending unicode characters remains. I feel there must be a better and shorter way but can't find any. Can anyone please help?

Comment: your best friend is Windows Hooking and API hooking ,,, also you may can register some sort of input method or device ...

Comment: I'm sure there is some sort of input and keyboard registering api I should search for it